# Determine how much order/structure is present in a 2D array of values

Tags: entropy, pattern-recognition, randomness, fourier-transform

I have a large 2D array of numbers that may or may not be totally random. I would like to examine this array for signs of non-randomness, such as repeating patterns or other two-dimensional structures. What is the best way to do this?

Is a 2D Fast Fourier Transform a good approach? (In other words, a 2D analog of the DFT randomness test described [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-22-rev1a/SP800-22rev1a.pdf).) If so, how do I interpret the output for signs of non-randomness?

I'm a software developer, not a data scientist, so please bear with me if this seems like an obvious question. Thanks.

Comment: What do the numbers represent?  Are they generated independently, or do they represent some proportion/allocation of fixed line and column totals?

Comment: They're independent, like pixels in an image. They don't have any intrinsic meaning.

Comment: OK, do the numbers have any set limits or distribution?  What do you mean by random?  0 to 1?  Normal distribution?  Uniform distribution?  What would the numbers be on average, and with what variance, assuming complete randomness?  I assume that the number 1,234,567 is less likely to appear than the number 1, right?  How so?

Comment: Each number in the array is a small non-negative integer - let's say 0, 1, or 2. I don't know enough about randomness to say much about the distribution. If it's easier, you can think of each value in the array as being a single on/off bit. I'm trying to determine if the 2D array of bits is random or contains any patterns.

Comment: Understood, but since we can't define "pattern" other than "non-random", all we can do is to define what we mean by "random", and then figure out the probability of not being random.  If that makes sense.

Comment: I'd rather not have to define those terms, since there are already existing tests for randomness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests. All I'm looking for is a similar test that takes a 2D array of values instead of a 1D array.

Comment: There are always "patterns"...a "pattern" is a subjective thing, not something "out there"...what you are likely after is some sort of relationship that will hold for new samples, and not just this particular array. Correct?

Comment: Also, what would it mean for your array to NOT have a pattern? Is it fair to say that random means each pixel is assigned one of its possible values with equal probability?

Comment: Those are good questions, but they've already been answered by smarter people than me. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests for details. I'm just looking for a similar test that works with 2D input instead of 1D.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Slide 15 of [this presentation](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~johnmc/comp528/lecture-notes/Lecture22.pdf) addresses your issue. Its called the Serial Test and it basically breaks your array into a number of equal sized blocks, and checks if the are statistically the same.

A simple computational test will be to generate 1000's of random arrays, where you break each into a number of sub-blocks. Then, calculate the standard deviation of the mean of each cell for each trial. This will result in a histogram of standard deviations. If your actual array has sub-block standard deviation of the means much less or greater than this, then something is unusual;

Comment: Ah, thank you. I think this is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Will give it a try.